# Mongoose search from populated document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this simplified Mongoose Schema:

```
    UserSchema = new db.Schema({
        _id      : { type: db.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        name     : { type : String },
        friends  : [{ type: db.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }]
    })
```

I want to get all `friends` with `name` that starts with a certain key string, let's say 'Pe' should return records 'Peter' and 'Petra'.

So I tried populating the friends field first:

```
user.Model
            .findOne({
                _id : loggedId,
            })
            .select('friends')
            .populate('friends', 'name')
            .exec(function(err, results) {
                console.log(results);
            });
```

That will return **all** the user's friends and their `name` which is not really what I want.

How do I return only those with a name that starts with certain characters?

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

You can add options to the populate call.

See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.populate